# uppercase 'N' before prolog term: imp(P,Q,Y) :- not(P,NP),or(NP,Q,Y)

Tags: prolog

What is the uppercase 'N' before prolog term mean?

such as the P in imp becomes NP in not？

```
imp(P,Q,Y) :- not(P,NP),or(NP,Q,Y).
```

NP means negation of P in prolog?

N is a kind of built in function in prolog?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has no special meaning. The term `NP`, which starts with an upper case, means that it is a variable (it could start with any upper case letter).

The way I read your procedure:

```
imp(P,Q,Y) :- not(P,NP),or(NP,Q,Y).
```

it means: ' to get P implies Q onto variable Y' we call procedure `not/2` to get the negation of input P, and then we call procedure `or/3` which computes "not P or Q" onto variable Y. Of course you have somewhere defined procedures `not/2` and `or/3`